# Why does : prevent ${username=`whoami`} from throwing an error?

Tags: bash, shell

Why does

```
${username=`whoami`}
```

throw an error, whereas

```
: ${username=`whoami`}
```

performs an assignment without any ill effects?

I understand `:` is a placeholder. What is its use in this command? Is it the equivalent of running `: 'whoami'`?

---

For reference, the former usage was previously referred to as #3, and the new one as #4.

Comment: `:` is `true`, it doesn't do anything with the rest of the line @ `#4`. In short: if `${username=`whoami`}` doesn't result in the name of a function / command you want to run, don't run it like `#3`. Not then `$()` is an _entirely new subshell_, which is why you can't use any variables used there, as they well disappear as soon as that shell ends.

Comment: ...if your only outstanding questions are how #3 and #4 differ, I'd cut out everything else (and really, at that point you don't need a list at all).

Comment: Done. Kept the list for references to it in comments

Comment: I did a more extensive refactor on top, but left in the numbering references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
${parameter=value}
```

does two things: It has the side effect of assigning `value` to `parameter` if `parameter` is not already set, and the direct effect of expanding to the value of `parameter` when complete.

The error is the result of that direct effect: When you run

```
${user=`whoami`}
```

...on its own line, then that expands to, and tries to run, the output of `whoami` as a command. Let's say that the user variable is not previously assigned to, and the output of `whoami` is `james`; it would then try to run the command `james`, which would throw an error.

By contrast, running

```
: ${user=`whoami`}
```

...first performs the side effect (of doing an assignment to `user` if `user` is not already set), and then runs:

```
: james
```

...which has no effect, so only the side effect (of the assignment) is performed.

Comment: I didn't think it was obvious why you replaced with `:=`, so I made a comment.

Comment: `:` is a shortcut for `true`.

Comment: @EdouardThiel, ...well. In original 70s-era Bourne shell, `:` was a builtin whereas `true` ran `/bin/true`, so there was actually an efficiency difference between them. Arguably, if one is writing code that'll run on obsolete platforms, it's still a thing to keep in mind.

Comment: @imagineerThis, heh. That wasn't an intentional replacement -- I'm in the habit of using `:=` in my own code, so it's where my finger memory is -- so I've backed it out.

Answer (score 3):

In #3, according to the bash manual pages, you are trying to execute the whoami command output, i.e, if whoami command output is "peter", #3 means that the "peter" command is invoked. Moreover, "username" variable is assigned the value "peter"

The bash manual describes `${parameter:=word}` as follows:

> Assign Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter. The value of parameter is then substituted. Positional parameters and special parameters may not be assigned to in this way.

Likewise, for the `:` command --

> No effect; the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing any specified redirections. A zero exit code is returned.